# ReactiveCocoa: How to prevent RACSignal from being executed twice in parallel?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, reactive-cocoa

In my app i use ReactiveCocoa and the AFNetworking-Extension for API-Calls.
For each API-Endpoint i have a method starting the API-Request and returning the RACSignal.

With the results of the API-Calls i populate mostly UITableViews.

There are multiple events, which result in Reloading/Refreshing the View per API-Request:

- at the launch of the application
- viewDidAppear in every Tab
- when the user uses PullToRefresh
- when the app decides by itself to get new data at anytime

How can i prevent, that new API-Requests will be executed before an currently executing request to the same endpoint has finished?

I know, that i can use "throttle" to throttle user-inputs like tap-events. But as already mentioned there are several occasions which can start a new API-Request.

I could work with flags, which are set when starting the request and will be resetted in "completed"-block.

But are there built-in methods in ReactiveCocoa to use instead of?

Comment: You are looking for a `RACCommand`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jakub-Vanu mention RACCommand is your friend here.

You can have a RACCommand that returns a signal that sends the results of the network request as Next events.

```
let apiFetchCommand: RACCommand = RACCommand(signalBlock: { [weak self](object: AnyObject!) -> RACSignal! in
    return self.fetchSignal()
})
```

Then if you want a signal to that sends the next events that come from that commmand you can user the `executionSignals` property on RACCommand.

```
let fetchedResultsSignal: RACSignal = self.apiFetchCommand.executionSignals.switchToLatest()
```

This signal can be used to listen to the results from that command.

RACCommands have a property called `allowsConcurrentExecution` which is defaulted to false. This means that the command will not fire if the signal it returns has not yet completed.

Then to execute the command just call

```
self.apiFetchCommand.execute(someObject)
```